# How to combine groupby.size() and .sum() to extract data to new df (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I a data frame with categories and counts that I'd like to extract

```
data = {'Name' : ['John', 'Paul', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'George'], 'Count': [ 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I want to make a new df that has the number of times each name shows up and the sum of each of the 'Count' cells grouped by the name.

I know that I can use `df.groupby(['Name']).size().to_frame().reset_index()` to get a new df with the names and the number of times each name shows up, but I also need the sum of 'Count' for each name. However, when I try

```
new_df['Count'] = df.groupby('Name')['Count'].aggregate('sum')
```

I end up with

| Name | Size | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | Nan |
| Paul | 2 | Nan |
| George | 2 | Nan |
| Ringo | 1 | Nan |

instead of

| Name | Size | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 4 |
| Paul | 2 | 11 |
| George | 2 | 8 |
| Ringo | 1 | 7 |

I'm sure it must be something I'm doing wrong with the `.groupby('Name)` operation but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `df.groupby('Name')['Count'].agg(['size', 'sum'])`

Comment: @QuangHoang by now, if I see a pandas question. I know in next 5 mint, I am gonna read your name. Kudos mate.

Comment: The error you have stems from the index mismatch: you can check the indices of `new_df` and `df.groupby('Name')['Count'].aggregate('sum')`. When they don't align (as is the case here), pandas puts NaN for mismatched indices (all of them in your case). So you can try removing `reset_index()` from `df.groupby(['Name']).size().to_frame().reset_index()` if you'd like to do it your way.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks a million, this did exactly what I want.

Comment: @Neither thanks for the explanation, this was really useful in helping me understand what was going on.